# How can I improve my Java code to generate all known Perfect numbers?

Tags: java, algorithm, performance, biginteger, perfect-numbers

I'm trying to generate all known `perfect numbers` using `Euclid–Euler theorem`,

I was wondering if I can **modify/rewrite** my code to get **the results quickly**.

Here is my code:

```
   public static BigInteger[] genAllPerfect(int howMany)
   {
      int[] expn = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203, 2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689,
            9941, 11213, 19937, 21701, 23209, 44497, 86243, 110503, 132049, 216091, 756839, 859433, 1257787, 1398269,
            2976221, 3021377, 6972593, 13466917, 20996011, 24036583, 25964951, 30402457, 32582657, 37156667, 42643801,
            43112609, 57885161, 74207281, 77232917, 82589933 };

      BigInteger[] perfectNums = new BigInteger[51];
      BigInteger One = BigInteger.ONE;
      BigInteger Two = One.add(One);

      for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
      {
         BigInteger firstPart = Two.pow(expn[i] - 1); // 2^(p-1)

         BigInteger secondPart = Two.pow(expn[i]); // 2^p

         secondPart = secondPart.subtract(One); // (2^p - 1)

         perfectNums[i] = firstPart.multiply(secondPart);
      }

      return perfectNums;
   }
```

This code takes **30 sec** in average. 
Thanks.

Comment: What is your input value for `howMany`?

Comment: You should post this on our sister site [CodeReview.SE]. Be sure to include fully functional code that anyone can copy/paste and run. Specifically, you'll need to put your function inside a class and include a `main()` function to show how it is called.

Comment: Because you're only raising `2` a large power, you should use `BigInteger#shiftLeft` instead of `BigInteger#pow`.

Comment: setBit() will be the most appropriate here, Get a zero BigInteger and then set the bit position you need to get 2^n.

Comment: @JacobG.: That won't make much difference, as `pow()` contains code that treats powers of 2 as a special case and -- guess what -- just shifts the argument to the left.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I rewrite the formula to fit with Java BigInteger class setBit() method to reduce time.

```
2^(p-1) * (2^p -1)

= (2^p)/2 * (2^p -1)

= ((2^p) * (2^p -1))/2

= (2^2p - 2^p)/2

= (2^(2p-1) - 2^(p-1))
```

Since `2^n` can be calculate fast using `BigInteger` `setBit()` method. `setBit` is the fastest since it works with a single bit only.

Here is the complete code, it **takes around 0.35 seconds** for **all 51 perfect numbers** in my machine.

```
public class PerfectNumbers
{
   static BigInteger[] genAllPerfect(int howMany)
   {
      if (howMany > 51)
         howMany = 51;

      int[] expn = { 2, 3, 5, 7, 13, 17, 19, 31, 61, 89, 107, 127, 521, 607, 1279, 2203, 2281, 3217, 4253, 4423, 9689,
            9941, 11213, 19937, 21701, 23209, 44497, 86243, 110503, 132049, 216091, 756839, 859433, 1257787, 1398269,
            2976221, 3021377, 6972593, 13466917, 20996011, 24036583, 25964951, 30402457, 32582657, 37156667, 42643801,
            43112609, 57885161, 74207281, 77232917, 82589933 };

      BigInteger Zero = BigInteger.ZERO;
      BigInteger[] perfectNums = new BigInteger[howMany];

      for (int i = 0; i < howMany; i++)
      {
         BigInteger perfect1 = Zero.setBit(expn[i] - 1); // 2^(p-1)

         perfectNums[i] = Zero.setBit(2 * expn[i] - 1); // 2^(2*p-1)

         perfectNums[i] = perfectNums[i].subtract(perfect1); // 2^(2*p-1) - 2^(p-1)
      }
      return perfectNums;
   }
```

Comment: Wow! in my computer it takes 0.3 sec.